# jquery dialog box opens ok however closing fails

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a jquery dialog box that I am having a few problems with. If I press the button "my-button" the dialog opens ok, however if I try pressing the close button I get an error "Error: $("#dialog").dialog is not a function"

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in my script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        position: ["center", 200],
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Create Call',
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("CreateContactPartial")");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Enter":function () {
                alert('pressed');
            },
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    $('#my-button').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle and got the close button to work:
    http://jsfiddle.net/x45hD/

I changed this:

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action('CreateContactPartial')");
```

But, I'm not sure if that is the cause.

Comment: Hmm I tried your suggestion but an error 'Too many characters in character literal'

Comment: Have you tried taking out the $(this).load("@Url.Action('CreateContactPartial')"); and testing if the close button works? That's what the problem is, correct? It seems to be working fine in the jsfiddle which leads me to believe there is something going on the in $(this).load("@Url.Action('CreateContactPartial')"); call.

Comment: What is inside the partial appears to be jamming up the jquery. Do you have quotes or an apostrophe in the literal text you are writing into your javascript?

Comment: Yes you are right. I guess my next step is to look into whats going wrong with my asp.net mvc loading of the partial view

Answer (score 0):

try to use this
`window.parent.$(this).dialog('close');`
or
`window.$(this).dialog('close');`